# Share files with between group of user using Microsoft Live sdk

Tags: file-sharing, live-sdk, onedrive

I am developing an application that requires to share files between users using Microsoft Live sdk. But only resource that I came across is by providing [a shared link or embed link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659731.aspx#get_links_to_files_and_folders) which expires after some time and are open to public usage. Instead, I want to share files among only certain group of one drive users and that too, permanently. This functionality is already present in one drive itself. Is there any way of doing it using one drive api ?

UPDATE: [google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing) supports these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OneDrive API support the creation of [sharing links](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/sharing_createLink.htm), which would be easy to send to the group that you want to give access to a specific file or folder.  These links do not expire, however they can be revoked.

Here is an example of the kind of request you can use to create one of these links

```
POST https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{item-id}/action.createLink
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "type": "view"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible in Microsoft Live SDK ?

Comment: Nope, the LiveSDK does not support unlimited duration sharing links

Comment: Finally, I used one drive library (C#) available on github by one drive team. Only authentication component had to be changed as it was based on win32. I used web authentication broker and it's working.Thanks Peter.
(Permission is still public for these links)